# Include has_many results in REST JSON result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a Model called `List` that `has_many :entries`.  As usual, Rails 3 generated this show method for `List`

```
def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @list }
    end
end
```

How can I change `format.json` to include the `entries` results from `@list` in the json response as well?

I know I could convert `@list` to a Hash, add the Hash value of `.entries` to that, then render the Hash, but I suspect that Rails has a more elegant trick up its sleeve.

Comment: `@list = List.find(params[:id]).joins(:entries)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there's an `:include` option you can give to `to_json`:

```rb
format.json { render json: @list.to_json(:include => :entries) }
```

Comment: This also works with multiple models, e.g.:  `@list.to_json(:include => [:entries, :owners])`  and you may want to optimise your initial SQL query by using include there too, e.g.: `@list = List.includes([:entries, :owners]).find(params[:id])`

Comment: it would be better if you use `as_json` that way it won't stringify the response.