# Getting has_many association from ngResource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to recreate the following erb template in angularjs using ngResource, but can't seem to figure out how to access the event.spikes (it's a has_many relationship).

The erb file I want to change:

```
<div class='event-list'>
  <ul>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
    <li><%= event.name %> || <small><%= event.date %></small>
      <ul>
        <% event.spikes.each do |spike| %>
        <li>Time of Spike: <%= spike.date_time %> || Spike Velocity: <%= spike.peak_velocity %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>     
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The half finished .html without erb:

```
<div class='event-list' ng-controller='EventsCtrl'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='event in events'>
      {{ event.name }} || <small>{{ event.date }}</small>
      <ul>
        <<<<<SOMETHING GOES HERE???>>>>>>>>
      </ul>     
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my service, app/assets/javascripts/angular/controllers/event.js:

```
App.factory('Event', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/events/:id', { id: '@id' });
}]);
```

My angular controller, app/assets/javascripts/angular/controllers/events.ctrl.js:

```
App.controller('EventsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Event', function($scope, Event) {
  $scope.events = Event.query();
}]);
```

And where my angular app is defined, app/assets/javascripts/app.js:

```
window.App = angular.module('sportsSpike', ['ngResource']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest in Angular like this

```
<li ng-repeat='event in events'>
      {{ event.name }} || <small>{{ event.date }}</small>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='spike in event.spikes'>
          {{ spike.some_output_value }}  
        </li>
      </ul>     
</li>
```

You will, however need to ensure that the way you are passing the data to angular has already resolved the `spike` property of `events`.

Hope this helps

Comment: (repeated above): Thanks for the answer.  So I guess the meat of the question I have then is how do I resolve the spike property on events.  In my factory do I need to return a $resource('some/route') that contains the events spikes?  It doesn't seem to work without an explicit retrieval of the event.spikes somewhere in my angular code.  In other words, it's not as simple as calling the active record method, .spikes.

Comment: I tend to pass the data around as JSON, so if you resolve the spikes in the controller e.g. `@event = Event.find(id: params[:id]).includes(:spikes)` then send as JSON via your respond to block e.g. `format.json {render json: @event}`.  I'm not sure this is exactly your model structure etc. but the principle should be workable.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from *muttonlamb* here it is a complete HTML file. As explained before you can easily nest `ng-repeat` with AngularJS and new child isolated scopes will be created.

You can see full code below or plunker here (http://plnkr.co/edit/jRG4xcRIab8sgHJFffWV)

P.S.: I am not using any ngResource just for simplicity as I am fetching the data via an array, but the `ng-repeat` code will work either way.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Events</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

 <script>

 'use strict';

 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


 myApp.events = [

       {
          name: 'Event 1',
          date: '01/02/2013',
          spikes: [
              {
                date_time : '1288323623006',
                peak_velocity: '10m/s'
              },

              {
                date_time : '1288323623004',
                peak_velocity: '20m/s'
              },
              {
                date_time : '1288323623003',
                peak_velocity: '10m/s'
              },

              {
                date_time : '1288323623001',
                peak_velocity: '20m/s'
              }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Event 2',
      date: '05/03/2013',
      spikes: [
              {
                date_time : '1288323623003',
                peak_velocity: '40m/s'
              },

              {
                date_time : '1288323623002',
                peak_velocity: '50m/s'
              },
              {
                date_time : '1288323623007',
                peak_velocity: '80m/s'
              },

              {
                date_time : '1288323623001',
                peak_velocity: '60m/s'
              }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Event 2',
      date: '05/03/2013',
      spikes: [
              {
                date_time : '1288323623005',
                peak_velocity: '40m/s'
              },

              {
                date_time : '1288323623009',
                peak_velocity: '50m/s'
              },
              {
                date_time : '1288323623003',
                peak_velocity: '80m/s'
              },

              {
                date_time : '1288323623002',
                peak_velocity: '60m/s'
              }
      ]
    }


  ];


  myApp.controller('EventsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Event', function($scope, Event) {

    $scope.events = Event.query();

  }]);

  myApp.factory('Event', function() {

    return {

        query: function() {
          return myApp.events;
        }

    } 

  });


  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div class='event-list' ng-controller='EventsCtrl'>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='event in events'>
    <h3>{{ event.name }} || {{ event.date }}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='spike in event.spikes'>
        Time of Spike: {{ spike.date_time | date : 'short' }}  || Spike Velocity: {{ spike.peak_velocity }} 
      </li>
    </ul>     
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (repeated below): Thanks for the answer.  So I guess the meat of the question I have then is how do I resolve the spike property on events.  In my factory do I need to return a $resource('some/route') that contains the events spikes?  It doesn't seem to work without an explicit retrieval of the event.spikes somewhere in my angular code.  In other words, it's not as simple as calling the active record method, .spikes.

Comment: You can make rails include the spikes in the request for the events using `#to_json(:include => :events)`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159735/include-has-many-results-in-rest-json-result